# Insert custom slide layout into current position

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I know one can insert a PowerPoint layout with one of the standard PpSlideLayout constants (e.g.: ppLayoutBlank) into current position however I cannot figure out to do the same with custom slide layout. (e.g. as below with 01 Divider slide numbered.)

The code below inserts the custom slide layout named 01 Divider slide numbered at the end of the PowerPoint presentation.

```vb
'Insert Divider page layout
Sub Add01DividerSlideNumbered()
    Dim oSlides As Slides, oSlide As Slide
    Set oSlides = ActivePresentation.Slides
    Set oSlide = oSlides.AddSlide(oSlides.Count + 1, GetLayout("01 Divider slide numbered"))
End Sub

'Callback for customButton onAction
Sub Adds01DividerSlideNumbered(control As IRibbonControl)
    Call Module1.Add01DividerSlideNumbered
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the current slide index as follows...

```
ActivePresentation.Windows(1).View.Slide.SlideIndex
```

Comment: Hi thank you for that 

I landed up using

Comment: Sub Add01DividerSlideNumbered()
    Dim oSlides As Slides, oSlide As Slide

    Dim currentSlide As Slide
    Dim slideIndex As Long
    Set currentSlide = Application.activeWindow.view.Slide
    slideIndex = currentSlide.slideIndex

    Set oSlides = ActivePresentation.Slides
    Set oSlide = oSlides.AddSlide(slideIndex + 1, GetLayout("01 Divider slide numbered"))
End Sub